# Windows 10: turn off screen in X amount of seconds on Y power plan

Tags: windows-10

I've been googling vehemntly about how one can turn off one's monitor after X amount of seconds, but only when the PC on a specific power plan. Does anyone have any idea how one could possibly solve this?

Comment: The minimum amount of time supported is one minute. Also, the setting has been part of the power plan for more than 10 years now. What exactly isn’t working/sufficient for you?

Comment: @DanielB The reason why I want it to be less than a minute, is because when I go to bed, I set my PC to Power Saving mode, but often times the screen gets activated for some reason a couple of times during the night, which can be somewhat unconducive for sleep... so yeah, would be nice for the screen to go off almost instantly, whenever it gets activated.

Comment: So even if the timeout were seconds, the screen would still turn on. Just turn the screen itself off...?

Comment: @DanielB yeah, but at least it wouldn't be as noticeable I guess... I've got 6 screens, so turning all of them off every night and back on every morning is gonna be too much of a hassle... putting the PC to sleep mode isn't an option for me either, because it messes up my custom taskbar setup on each monitor every time.

I guess as an alternative, it would be nice to be able to turn off screen with a hotkey, and turn it back on ONLY with the set hotkey...